# Using LIKE clause in a query

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, sql-like

I am trying to write a dynamic query which is getting information from several dropdown list.
and in the drop down lists is an option named `ANY` that I gave the value `%` so that when it is chosen, then it does not affect the query selection.

This is my query:

```
$query_pag_data = "
SELECT *
FROM forecast
WHERE QuoteCode IN
    (SELECT QuoteCode
     FROM `StockData`
     WHERE AssetType LIKE '$sec'
       AND region LIKE '$indust'
       AND exchange LIKE '$exchange'
       AND Country LIKE '$cntry')
  AND RANKING LIKE '$sig_m_t'
  AND RANKINGw '$sig_l_t'
  AND NewSigD LIKE '$new_m'
  AND NewSigW LIKE '$new_l'
ORDER BY SCORE DESC LIMIT $start,
                          $per_page
";
```

I wanted to know is it working if I pass `%` in a variable?

Comment: Sure it will work, because before you pass query to sql server, it's editable as you wish. But can you post php code also?

Comment: Maybe you forgot the %-sign in your search strings.

Answer (score 2):

What i do in these cases is :

```
$query_pag_data = "
SELECT *
FROM forecast
WHERE QuoteCode IN
(SELECT QuoteCode
FROM `StockData`
WHERE AssetType LIKE '%$sec%'
AND region LIKE '%$indust%'
AND exchange LIKE '%$exchange%'
AND Country LIKE '%$cntry%'
AND RANKING LIKE '%$sig_m_t%'
AND RANKINGw '%$sig_l_t%'
AND NewSigD LIKE '%$new_m%'
AND NewSigW LIKE '%$new_l%'
ORDER BY SCORE DESC LIMIT $start,$per_page";
```

Comment: With """ you dont have to concatenate, php process the string and replace the variables ;)

Comment: I'm not sure as to what should be remove to get the code optimal, please let me know what characters should be removed.  The code should work either way I believe.

Comment: Yes the code works but it's faster to do "LIKE '%$new_m.%'" than '%".$new_m."%'" ;)

Comment: Nice to know, "LIKE '%$new_m.%'" is the . after the variable a typo or is it needed ?

Comment: It's a typo. sorry ^^